# Reference native c++ dll in UWP project

Tags: c#, c++, dll, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a c++ dll that I want to utilize in the UWP project that I am working on. I need some assistant on how to achieve that.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620704/calling-loadlibrary-using-pinvoke-from-uwp-c-sharp-application

Comment: ^ that question is unrelated to this one.

Comment: Try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611410/calling-native-c-from-managed-c-sharp-in-windows-store

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use C++ DLLs in C# code in a UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489924/can-you-use-c-dlls-in-c-sharp-code-in-a-uwp)

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have a concept of "referencing DLLs". All you need to do to use them is to make sure they're copied next to your executable when you build your app. If you're using Visual Studio C# project (.csproj), add it to it as "Content" type:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
  <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)MyDLL\x86\MyDLL.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
  <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)MyDLL\x64\MyDLL.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Once you have this setup, it's just a matter of P/Invoking into it, for instance:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
void DoStuff();
```

Comment: _"`C++` doesn't have a concept of "referencing DLLs"."_ - doesn't read correctly.  Did you mean C#?  Also, just copying a native dll next to your UWP app doesn't mean it will pass UWP sandboxing as mentioned in [Bite's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387168/585968)

Comment: It will pass the certification as long as the DLL is compiled with UWP SDK. And no, I didn't mean C#, as you can reference C# assemblies from projects.

Answer (score 0):

> Universal Windows Apps run in a restricted runtime environment, so you can't just use any native DLL the way you would in a classic Windows desktop application. If you have source code for a DLL, you can port the code so that it runs on the UWP. You start by changing a few project settings and project file metadata to identify the project as a UWP project. You need to compile the library code using the /ZW option, which enables C++/CX. Certain API calls are not allowed in UWP apps due to stricter controls associated with that environment. See Win32 and COM APIs for UWP apps.

If your native DLL exposes functions using `__declspec(dllexport)`, then you could follow the procedure on [Using a Win32 DLL in a UWP App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2017#BK_Win32DLL).