# How to import a c++ dll as a reference in c# UWP project?

Tags: c#, c++, uwp

I am trying to import a c++ dll in a C# UWP project. 
Steps:

1. Place the dll in the bin folder.
2. Try to P/Invoke the dll using
   DllImport.
3. System.Typeload Exception occurs telling to look in
   build warnings

In the build warnings, I get a MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke Method warning. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime.

Comment: Does your dll have the function that you P/Invoke?

Comment: This warning can be generated when you build the Release version with .NET Native enabled.  Simplest explanation is that you tested the Debug build but forgot to copy the DLL for the Release build.

Comment: @MertGülsoy Yes.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2017#BK_Win32DLL

Comment: @HansPassant I unchecked the option. I have placed the debug and release builds of the dll in their respective folder under bin/. It gives me a system.dllNotfoundException.

Comment: Copying DLL isn't enough. You need to add it to your project. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358569/reference-native-c-dll-in-uwp-project/53368462#53368462

Comment: And be careful with calling  conventions it's likely cdecl
```[DllImport("myDll.dll", EntryPoint = "function", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

extern int function(primativeType args);```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/dlls-c-cx?view=vs-2017  -- Create a Windows Runtime Component proeject and include your dll or static library and export the functions. Include the winmd file as a reference in the UWP project and use DllImport as mentioned by @AvishaiDernis !